# Can I chain async task sequentially (starting one after the previous asynctask completes)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Every time I do a `httpRequest`, the screen will appear to be locked up for a few seconds while the code is executing. Hence I used `AsyncTask` to do all my `httpRequest` stuff in a separate thread while putting up a `ProgressDialog` so the user knows something is happening.

I recently encountered the following situation: the input of one of my `httpRequest` is dependent on the result from a previous `httpRequest` (+parse) action. I can't just put the two `AsyncTask`s sequentially cause Android will put them in two threads and start the second one without the first one being finished. And without an appropriate input (the result of the first `httpRequest`), my second `httpRequest` will crash the app.

Is there way I can put-in a `wait()` to force the second `AsyncTask` not to start until the first one finishes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I also had some same situation the other day.
I had solved it in this way:
Pass the reference of your activity to the constructor of async class and execute the do in background function. Now in post execute function call a public method of ur activity from async class to execute the task again... or try this:

```
            if (asynclass.getStatus() == android.os.AsyncTask.Status.PENDING) {
                asynclass.execute();
            } else if (RF.getStatus() == android.os.AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
                asynclass = new asyncclass();
                asynclass.execute();
            } else {
                Toast.maketoast(this, "Plz wait", 1).show();
            }
```

Cheers

Comment: +1 Yes agree with @Await, we can get the status of any AsyncTask by using getStatus() method.

Comment: I considered doing what you and @nik suggested to just call the 2nd asynctask in the postExcute function, but is it a bad practice to call an asynctask within another ansyctask?

Answer (score 6):

so i think(not sure),you need to call second asyncTask on post execution method

```
protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
            if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
                this.dialog.dismiss();
                     new secTask().execute();
            }}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. But it is only possible in `onProgressUpdate()` or `onPostExecute()`. Try doing it like this:

```
private class Task1 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
...
...
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) { 
        dialog1.dismiss();
        new Task2().execute();
    }

}
```

Similarly, you'll have to put `new Task3().execute();` in the `onPostExecute()` method of Task2's `AsyncTask`

Don't call them like this in your main code. If you do, then all of them will run together:

```
// This is wrong
new Task1().execute();
new Task2().execute();
new Task3().execute();
```

Reference: [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 3):

How about using [`executOnExecutor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...)) method :

```
public void runTasks() {

        AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> aTask = myTask();
        AsyncTask<Void,Void,Integer> aTask1 = myTask1();
        AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> aTask2 = myTask2();

        aTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
        aTask1.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
        aTask2.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);

    }
```

Comment: But this way you won't be able create some sort of flow control. Oh, my bad, you still can do that in the onPreExecute callback.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled on this thread looking for a better solution than what I currently use, but it still seems the best...

What I do is pass a runnable in the constructor of each of my async tasks.

Either in the post execute or at the end of the do in the background, I launch my next task, if I have one by executing the runnable.

```
 if(doOnPostExec != null)
        doOnPostExec.run();
```

This way I can changeup the order of my asynctasks by the runnables I pass keeping the code flexible, and if I pass no runnable they complete normally.   The runnables just contain one line calling the next asynctask.

I just don't like making all those runnables.  Was hoping something existed like in vb.net for chaining delegates.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem before. What I did is use a call back interface class and call its method inside the onPostExecute() method. This way you can call another AsyncTask from the callback method.