# Advice about AsyncTask

Tags: android-asynctask

I´m new with Android and I need any advice about Asyntask topic.
Currently I´ve a app that I write some information and using AsyncTask I send to SAP System (BackEnd) using HttpURLConnection. I´m going to write a second Asyntask to send a photo using FTP protocol to another server.

So I´ve going to have two Asyntask one for the data with SAP and another with a ftp server to send a photo.

I have a listview with several lines of information, for each row I want use the first Asyntask and if it´s OK, I will use the second Asyntask.

When the first row was processed (with OK or wrong finish), the I want start with the first Asyntask and the second Asyntask and go on...

So How can I do it ????

Somethin like this:

http://shamansir.github.io/blog/articles/10-useful-solutions-for-android-developer/

(point 9. AsyncTask Queues )

http://blogs.innovationm.com/multiple-asynctask-in-android/

[Can I chain async task sequentially (starting one after the previous asynctask completes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494515/can-i-chain-async-task-sequentially-starting-one-after-the-previous-asynctask-c)

Any advice ????

Thansk in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can call another asynctask from [onPostExecute](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)). It will be called after the first one has finished, and the call will be made from ui thread.